# Regular Expression start-end position

Tags: c#, regex

I need to make a validation in a string with positional information using regex.

Example:

```
020005254877841100557810AAAAAA841158891BBBB
```

I need to get match position 5 until 10 and has to be only numbers.

How can I do this using RegEx?

Comment: Do u need a regex? Get a substring from 5 to 10 and check that all chars of said substring are digits..

Comment: The files are big, I think RegEx will be faster than substring and I can do other validation faster, like validate if it is a number or letter, or if a date is in a designated format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hmm does it really have to be regex?
I would have done like this.

```
var myString = "020005254877841100557810AAAAAA841158891BBBB";
var isValid = myString.Substring(4, 5).All(Char.IsDigit);
```

Comment: Need to compare to character literals of 0 and 9, since the Enumerable will return chars from the string.

Comment: I agree with Jason. A regular expression should be your last choice. They are expensive. That said there are definite times to use them.

Comment: How about `var isValid = myString.Substring(4, 5).All(Char.IsDigit);` ?

Comment: That's cool. I didn't know you could just place function names in like that.

Answer (score 6):

If you absolutely HAVE to use regex, here it is.... (Though I think you should go with something like Jonas W's answer).

```
Match m = Regex.Match(myString, "^.{4}\d{5}.*");

if(m.Success){
    //do stuff
}
```

The regex means, "from the beginning of the string (^), match 4 of any character (.{4}), then five digits, (\d{5}), then however many of any other characters (.*)"

Answer (score 0):

If you really feel you must use a regex this will be the one:

```
"^....\d{5}"
```

You can also do multiple checks like this:

```
"^....(\d{5}|\D{5})
```

That one will match all numbers or all non-digit characters, but not a mix or anything with whitespace.

Answer (score -1):

To build on what FailedDev mentioned.

```
string myString = "020005254877841100557810AAAAAA841158891BBBB";
myString.Substring(5, 5); //will get the substring at index 5 to 10.
double Num;
bool isNum = double.TryParse(myString, out Num); //returns true of all numbers
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: This will return a false positive if one of those characters is a period or the letter 'e' or begins with a '+' or '-'.  "12.34" is a valid double and so is "12e34" and "+1234" and "-12.4" and "+12E3".